# Unexpected property when serializing F# option field in record type with JSON.NET

Tags: json, f#, json.net, record

I have a relatively simple set of records in F# matching a JSON payload, for the purposes of (de)serialization. When I try to deserialize the payload, I get an error

```
Unexpected property 'tags' found when reading union. Path 'products[0].tags'
```

My record and payload match up in structure, but not in field name case; but I've added a `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` to the JSON.NET settings to address that.

When I remove the tags property from both the example payload and the record type, the error moves on to mention variants instead. I've also tried adding `CLIMutable` and `DataContract` attributes to the records. Adding a `JsonProperty` attribute to the field in question hasn't helped either.

Looking at the JSON.NET source, it appears this error appears when it can't find a union case with that name. However, in this case I'm dealing with a string in a record, so that doesn't make sense to me.

**Has anybody come across this before? Is this a limitation of the library?** Or am I using it wrong?

### Edit

Further investigation has thrown up that this appears to be an issue with serializing a `string option` type field in the record (now added to the code below) which has a value in the payload.

---

F#

```
type Product = {
    Id: int;
    Title: int;
    Tags: string;
    Variants: Variant list;
    Vendor: string option;
}

type ProductList = {
    Products: Product list
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "title": "A title",
            "tags": "some, tags"
            "variants": [],
            "vendor": "The Vendor"
            ...
        },
        ...   
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've not encountered this one, but I've encountered similar bugs when combining F# and custom serializers.  File it, and he's usually pretty quick to fix things.

Comment: This is turning out to be caused by trying to serialise an option type. I left it out of my original post because I didn't expect it to be the issue. Editing now.

Comment: What version of Json.Net are you using?  That may be related to a bug I filed and got fixed a few months ago.  If you're using an old one, try a newer release.

Comment: I'm using 7.0.1 targeting .NET 4.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Vendor` field serialized input is incrrect.  The `option` type is a discriminated union, and Json.NET expects all DUs to be serialized as `{"case":"blah","fields":["moreblah"]}`.  So in your case you should be using `"vendor":{"case":"Some","fields":["The Vendor"]}`.

I'd imagine someone somewhere has written an `option`-specific converter you can use if you can't change your serialized input.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I was assuming that the option type would be serialised as its value or null, but I guess not!

Comment: FYI checkout FsharpLu for simpler json conversion of F# things.